# Why does sudo command executed in rc.local file create two processes? One with the sudo command and one without

Tags: linux, sudo, rc.local

To run the process at boot time, I wrote a script in the rc.local file using the sudo command.

However, if you look up processes with the ps command, there are two processes, one with the sudo command and one without.

It doesn't affect the actual operation, but I wonder why two processes are created.

example

```
root       430     1  0 12월02 ?      00:00:00 sudo python3 process.py
root       511   423  0 12월02 ?      00:04:54 python3 process.py
```

can you answer me?

Comment: The duplicate doesn’t address the process tree shown by your `ps` output, as explained in roaima’s answer; if you’re curious about that, feel free to [edit] your question to ask about it and I’ll re-open.

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote a script in the rc.local file using the sudo command

You don't need to use `sudo`, as `rc.local` is executed as root anyway.

Nevertheless, let's look at what's going on here.

> ```
> root       430     1  0 12월02 ?      00:00:00 sudo python3 process.py
> root       511   423  0 12월02 ?      00:04:54 python3 process.py
> ```

Process 430 is the one invoked from `rc.local` where you use `sudo`. Process 511 is puzzling me a little, though; I would have expected its parent to be 430 but it seems to be from something even earlier. It would help to see the exact code section in your `rc.local`. It's the command actually invoked from `sudo`. When the process ends, the `sudo` will complete and it will also exit.

Comment: `sudo` was presumably reparented to `init`, which would be explained by its parent (`rc.local`) dying; but that doesn’t explain process 234.

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, that's what's puzzling